# Open two dialog together

Tags: java, android

I have two dialog.i open dialog one and click one button in adapter listview in dialog, and i want open another dialog to ask question for are you sure delet this item or no.
**But just i can open one of them at a time**.
What can i do?

```
viewHolder.btnDelet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            new DialogDelet(context).setOnListener(new ListenerDelet() {

                @Override

                public void onSuccess() {

                    listenerAdapterUserAndRole.unSelect(item);

                }



                @Override

                public void onCancel() {

                }

            }).Show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel first dialog when user is confirm or you want to open next dialog

like:

```
public void open(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,
                You wanted to make decision");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes 
                                        button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        //cancel first dialog here
                                        firstDialogObj.cancel;
                                // do your stuff contnious what you want
                            }
                        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: i can not close first dialog becuse my list view in  first dialog and i want use DialogPluse not alertdialog

Comment: Try this with your dialog  plusDialog.setExpanded(true) and plusDialog.setCancelable(true) .

Comment: plusDialog.setExpanded(true)?where use it?dialog secound or one?i use in twoice but dosent work

Comment: Use it for only first